# CNAME record for CDN not working

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to point cdn.mydomain.in to xxxxxx.rsc.cdn77.org. using DIGITAL OCEAN. What is wrong in my CNAME records? What am i missing?

```
$ORIGIN magiccrate.in.  
$TTL 1800  
magiccrate.in. IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.magiccrate.in. 146489033438 10800 3600 604800 1800  
magiccrate.in. 1800 IN NS ns1.digitalocean.com.  
magiccrate.in. 1800 IN NS ns2.digitalocean.com.  
magiccrate.in. 1800 IN NS ns3.digitalocean.com.  
www.magiccrate.in. 1800 IN CNAME mydomain.in.  
magiccrate.in. 1800 IN MX 10 aspmx1.googlemail.com.  
magiccrate.in. 1800 IN MX 10 aspmx9.googlemail.com.   
magiccrate.in. 1800 IN A xx.xx.xx.xx  
cdn.magiccrate.in. 1800 IN CNAME xxxxxx.rsc.cdn77.org.
```

When I do a DIG lookup it shows an A record to mydomain's IP. I am doing this essentially to set up a cdn for my domain.

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what's going on here without the real domain name.  I urge you **not** to redact your domain name (and if you must, please [do it properly](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts)).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this DNS server isn't being used. The records you posted indicate that the nameservers for your domain are `ns1.digitalocean.com`, `ns2.digitalocean.com`, and `ns3.digitalocean.com`. However, when I check for myself:

```
$ dig NS magiccrate.in

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> NS magiccrate.in
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 33068
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;magiccrate.in.                 IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
magiccrate.in.          1799    IN      NS      dns4.registrar-servers.com.
magiccrate.in.          1799    IN      NS      dns1.registrar-servers.com.
magiccrate.in.          1799    IN      NS      dns3.registrar-servers.com.
magiccrate.in.          1799    IN      NS      dns2.registrar-servers.com.
magiccrate.in.          1799    IN      NS      dns5.registrar-servers.com.
```

Comment: Thank you @ConnorJC. It was actually the nameserver due to which the CNAME was not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the record created correctly but if you are hoping to make a website redirect just using a CNAME record, it won't work. You either need to setup a 301 redirect or make sure that the host headers at xxxxxx.rsc.cdn77.org have cdn.mydomain.in so it will display the page.

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to set up a CDN for my domain @Skyler

Comment: You will need to work with the CDN provider because they have changes they need to make on their end now. Your CNAME record is created correctly from what you showed us. If you ping xxxxxx.rsc.cdn77.org, it will resolve to cdn.mydomain.in and ping the IP of your A record for cdn.mydomain.in.